# NetworkStream read skipping packets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a TCPClient using the async BeginRead to listen to a custom application. The listening code is this:

```
    ClientState cs;

    void Update()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (cs != null)
            {
                if (cs.bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    ReceiveNetworkMsg?.Invoke(cs.receiveBuffer, cs.bytesReceived);
                    Array.Clear(cs.receiveBuffer, 0, cs.bytesReceived);
                    cs.bytesReceived = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ListenForData()
    {
        Debug.Log("Listening");

        stream = client.GetStream();
        cs = new ClientState(stream);

        do
        {
            //stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, MessageReceived, client);
            stream.BeginRead(cs.buffer, 0, cs.buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), cs);
            yield return null;
        } while (client != null);
    }

    void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ClientState cs = (ClientState)result.AsyncState;

        lock (lockObj)
        {
            int currBytesReceived = cs.stream.EndRead(result);
            Array.Copy(cs.buffer, 0, cs.receiveBuffer, cs.bytesReceived, currBytesReceived);
            Debug.Log("Network receiving: " + currBytesReceived + " " + cs.bytesReceived + " bytes. " + BitConverter.ToString(cs.buffer, 0, currBytesReceived));
            cs.bytesReceived += currBytesReceived;
        }
    }
```

At a certain point when the server sends a series of messages, the bytes received does not match the actual bytes sent:

Wireshark log:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     35 0.619977       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      64     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=53 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=20

0000  14 00 23 11 4a 3e 01 01 1c 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ..#.J>..........
0010  02 01 22 00                                       ..".
    Data: 140023114a3e01011c1002000000000002012200
    [Length: 20]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     39 0.621735       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=73 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     43 0.623598       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=94 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     47 0.625630       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=115 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     51 0.627592       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=136 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     55 0.629683       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=157 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     59 0.632344       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      65     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=178 Ack=140 Win=28 Len=21

0000  15 00 99 b2 b6 07 01 01 06 10 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010  00 00 00 00 00                                    .....
    Data: 150099b2b607010106100200000000000000000000
    [Length: 21]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     65 0.634544       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      62     5001 → 49872 [PSH, ACK] Seq=199 Ack=166 Win=28 Len=18

0000  12 00 57 c1 55 6c 01 01 03 10 02 01 00 00 00 00   ..W.Ul..........
0010  00 02                                             ..
    Data: 120057c1556c010103100201000000000002
    [Length: 18]
```

Logs:

```
Network receiving: 20 0 bytes. 14-00-9D-59-A2-54-01-01-1C-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-02-01-1F-00

Network receiving: 21 20 bytes. 15-00-99-B2-B6-07-01-01-06-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Network receiving: 21 41 bytes. 15-00-99-B2-B6-07-01-01-06-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Network receiving: 21 62 bytes. 15-00-99-B2-B6-07-01-01-06-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Network receiving: 21 83 bytes. 15-00-99-B2-B6-07-01-01-06-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Network receiving: 21 104 bytes. 15-00-99-B2-B6-07-01-01-06-10-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Network receiving: 21 0 bytes. 12-00-57-C1-55-6C-01-01-03-10-02-01-00-00-00-00-00-02-00-00-00

Network receiving: 18 21 bytes. 12-00-57-C1-55-6C-01-01-03-10-02-01-00-00-00-00-00-02
```

After the 20 byte message, there are supposed to be 6 21 byte messages before the 18 byte one. My receive side first processes the first 5 21 byte message, then for some reason when it is trying to process the 6th 21 byte message it is returning the correct size but it is getting the 18 byte message.

Am I missing out on something fundamental here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the network stream received 21 bytes 6 times; what `ClientState` did with them between the 104 and the 0 - is up to `ClientState`, which: we can't see. It *sounds* like a competing thread made `ClientState` consume the buffer. Note, however, that IMO your expectations are incorrect here; I fundamentally disagree with the statement:

> there are supposed to be 6 21 byte messages before the 18 byte one

The code we're looking at is TCP, which deals in streams, not messages; there is no guarantee that it will arrive in 6 21-byte pieces. It could all arrive in a single 126-byte chunk, or it could arrive in 126 separate 1-byte pieces. All you are guaranteed is: the same bytes in the same order (or a failure, perhaps, if a broken socket is detected).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the consumer: it is in the Update in the main thread (also updated above).

Comment: @xilef so ... that just looks like `Update` happened before the final 21-byte message, clearing the buffer; what makes you think anything is wrong here? please be specific: what is the bit that is unexpected to you? Don't forget: your counts are *before* the append; and it isn't clear that you're limiting the byte output to *just* the active portion of the buffer

Comment: Yes the Update processed first before that final 21-byte. After that I was expecting that the EndRead will return me the final 21-byte size and the buffer to contain the message in packet No.59 above in the wireshark log. What I am getting though is a size of 21-byte but the buffer contains the message in packet No. 65.

Comment: @xilef from what are you drawing that conclusion? I'm familiar with network code, and I don't think that is a valid conclusion; what you should log here is: `BitConverter.ToString(cs.buffer, 0, currBytesReceived)` (during `ReadCallback`, and ideally inside the `lock`), because *that* is what we are receiving. Everything else you're seeing seems to be - from what I can see - timing issues re `Update`. It isn't shown when or how `Update` gets called, but that looks *hella* problematic

Comment: The update is Unity's Update callback. I'm assuming since the first 5 have already been processed, the next read should contain the payload from packet 59?

Comment: @FelixPalomares when do you progress the enumerator? I *strongly suspect* that what is happening here is : timing; suggestion - add logging for `BeginRead. Looking at that output, I think you're reading more often than you think you are (or at different times), and your array is being over-stamped

Comment: The ListenForData is run as a Coroutine. Interesting point on the reading more often and overwriting the array. I'll read up again on coroutines and redo the listen loop. I'll report back in 12 hours as I don't have access to the custom app now.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I rewrote the ListenForData and ReadCallback to ensure it will only be called once at a time and it seems to be working fine now.